# How to stop recursive login attempt to Jira when the password provided is incorrect?

Tags: python, jira, jira-rest-api

I am building a utility using python to connect to Jira and extract TEST coverage. As part of this tool, I am asking the user to enter the user credentials. The tool waits for user inputs like entering usid/pwd and once successful then ask for the Jira query to be provided. Then it runs the query and provides the results.

The issue here is, as a negative scenario I tried entering an incorrect password, but then Jira itself tries multiple times with that incorrect credentials and gets account locked.

**How can we stop this retry** in the first warning itself and catch that warning to alert the user to check his password/usid entered is correct? I tried in try /except block but it seems not catching it.

> WARNING:root:Got recoverable error from GET https://jira.xxxxxxcom/rest/api/2/serverInfo, will retry [1/3] in 1.5083078521975724s. Err: 401
>   WARNING:root:Got recoverable error from GET https://jira.xxxxxxcom/rest/api/2/serverInfo, will retry [2/3] in 35.84973140451337s. Err: 401

My code below :

```
pwd=input("Enter Jira credentials")
while True:
    **try:**
        jira = JIRA(options={'server': 'https://jira.dummy.com', 'verify': False}, basic_auth=(os.getlogin(), pwd))     //executing this line internally retry the same invalid credential many times
        return jira   // returns jira handle to another function to process.
        break
    **except JIRAError as e:**
        if (e.status_code == 401):
            print("Login to JIRA failed. Check your username and password")
            pwd = input("Enter your password again to access Jira OR you may close the tool ")
```

Answer (score 2):

A little late but for anyone else looking for the answer there is a max_retries property on the constructor of the JIRA object.

```
            self.__jira = JIRA(
                basic_auth=(username, password),
                max_retries=0,
                options={
                    'server': 'https://jira.dummy.com/'
                }
            )
```

You can see that and other variables in the source code https://jira.readthedocs.io/en/master/_modules/jira/client.html?highlight=max_retries#

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want the to prompt the user to enter valid credentials upon failure. You are not requesting the credentials every time you are trying the authentication, so move the input statement into the infinite loop and try this:

```py
while True:
    pwd=input("Enter Jira credentials")
    try:
        jira = JIRA(options={'server': 'https://jira.dummy.com', 'verify': False}, basic_auth=(os.getlogin(), pwd))     //executing this line internally retry the same invalid credential many times
        return jira   // returns jira handle to another function to process.
    except JIRAError as e:
        if (e.status_code == 401):
            print("Login to JIRA failed. Check your username and password")
            pwd = input("Enter your password again to access Jira OR you may close the tool ")
```

This will ask to enter the credentials one more time before you retry with the same old stuff. And there is no point in keeping break after return statement in the try statement.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The issue is, program control is not coming out of "jira=Jira(options=..... " statement itself. Internally in that statement, it is retrying multiple times and finally after all attempts it comes to the next line. So having the input statement inside also is not helping.Byt this time account would have locked.